# Why wont this CSS animation slide down and out?

Tags: css, animation, css-animations

Animating in and up is working but I cant understand why it won't slide down and out?

Instead of sliding down is just closes instantly.

Demo here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dYbaJB

JS:

```
$(function() {
  $("#btn").click(function () {
    if ($("#notification").hasClass("in")) {
      $("#notification")
        .removeClass("in")
        .addClass("out");
    } else {
      $("#notification")
        .removeClass("out")
        .addClass("in");
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply change your CSS to:

```
#notification.out 
{
     -webkit-animation-name: slideOutDown;
     animation-name: slideOutDown;
     bottom: 20px;
}
```